# Navigate up to activity which relies on intent extra data

Tags: android

So I have activities A, B and C.

A starts B, and passes it crucial data which it cannot function without via the Intent's extras. B starts C, then C finishes and navigates up via NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this). This causes B to re-start with an empty intent and no saved state, which causes my app to crash.

What would be the best way to still have the data I need in B when I navigate up to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what startActivityForResult was created for

Instead of starting Activity C, you start C with `startActivityForResult`

when you're done with C, you write

```
Intent returnData = new Intent();
returnData.putSomeExtras...
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnData);
finish();
```

this causes B's activity onActivityResult to be called, and your extras are in the Intent that is passed to this method

onActivity result usually looks like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
if(requestCode == REASON_I_STARTED_ACTIVITY_C){
//do something with data

}
}

}
```

and to start the activity you do something like this

```
public static final int REASON_I_STARTED_ACTIVITY_C = 100;

Intent startCIntent = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
startActivityForResult(startCIntent,REASON_I_STARTED_ACTIVITY_C);
```

***important note ***
onActivityResult is called BEFORE onResume of the activity it is executed in (B in this case)

Comment: I tried poking around at the solution you wrote, and while it works, it seems like the reason it works is not because of startActivityForResult, but rather because activity C is closed with a call to finish() instead of navigateUpFromSameTask(). I changed all my navigation calls to finish and it seems to work well without changing anything else... I wonder if that's the way it should be done, and if it is, why does navigateUpFromSameTask exists at all.

Comment: There are methods in android nobody understands, if you read the android code you will see comments like "method does nothing" , or "for this method to work, you also need to call... "

Comment: I didn't use setResult though, I just switched all nav calls to finish()

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to use SharedPreferences which will unconditionally help you and store an info you need always where you want to be stored.

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm